# Jstl iterate over a List

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I am trying to iterate over a list and trying to print the value as:

```
<jsp:useBean class="com.lftechnology.db.EmployeeDaoImpl" id="empImpl"></jsp:useBean>
<jsp:useBean class="com.lftechnology.employee.Employee" id="employee"></jsp:useBean>

<%
List<com.lftechnology.employee.Employee> empList = null; 
empList = empImpl.getAllEmployee();
out.println(empList.size());
%>


<c:forEach items="${empList}" var="element"> 
  <tr>
    <td>${element.name}</td>
    <td><c:out value="${element.name}" /></td>
     </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

However, only the size of the list is printed not the `name` as defined inside jstl. Any help? I want to print the all the attributes of `employee` object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you use the scriptlet at all? Something like this should work (I could not test it):

```
<jsp:useBean class="com.lftechnology.db.EmployeeDaoImpl" id="empImpl"></jsp:useBean>

<c:forEach items="${empImpl.allEmployee}" var="element"> 
  <tr>
    <td>${element.name}</td>
    <td><c:out value="${element.name}" /></td>
  </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

**Some background**

Just declaring a variable in a scriptlet does not automatically make it available to the JSTL runtime. In fact JSTL works on the `pageContext` injected into each JSP at runtime by the container. So if you really need to declare a variable in a scriptlet and want to make it available to JSTL you have to do this explicitly:

```
<%
List<String> stuff = new ArrayList<String>();
request.setAttribute("mystuff", stuff);
%>

<c:out value="${mystuff" />
```